# Best 2D game developing enviroment for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

First english isn't my primary language then I assume that I will have some grammatical mistakes.

I want to develop a 2D game for iOS.

What will be the best developing environment for iOS?

Will this developing environment require a legal OS system, or will I be able to develop in windows(without virtual machine)?

Which skill will it require in order to learn using those development environment and language and they includes have a basic physical system or will I have to program and design by myself some physical system ?

I would glad for some answers:)

Comment: use this or use google to find tutorials of 2dgames. http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Comment: u could also try for unity the latest also provides 2d development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xcode for development.

for 2d game you can use ios 7 SpriteKit, or for example Cocos2D(open source) + Box2D

cocos2d site http://cocos2d-iphone.org

or Sparrow http://gamua.com/sparrow/

Comment: Will it reuiqre a VM and mac in order to the veleop in xcode?

Comment: @Yoni yes you can use VM or mac, now i using VM at home without any problems.